# adding a Layerdefiniton file in QGIS 2.99

Tags: qgis

Wouldn't it be better to add the possibility of adding a Layerdefiniton file into a QGIS-map to the new Data Source Manager?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a "QGIS request forum" - you should post your suggestion over at https://issues.qgis.org/issues instead.

Comment: Okay, I will do so!